# Program to display a sum in C++?

Tags: c++

I was given a task to write a program that displays:

> [image]

I coded this:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
   clrscr();
   int a, n = 1, f = 1;
   float s = 0;
   cin >> a;
   while(n <= a)
   { 
        f = f * n;
        s += 1 / (float)f;
        n = n + 1;
   }

   cout << s;
   getch();
}
```

So this displays -

> s = 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! .... + 1/a!, including odd and even factorials.

For the past two hours I am trying to figure out how can I modify this code so that it displays the desired result. But I couldn't figure it out yet.

### Question:

What changes should I make to my code?

Comment: You are a bit unclear what actually should be displayed, the calculated result, or the verbatim text you show.

Comment: Try `n` in loop till  `2a` . That is condition `while(n<=2a)` . But you don't seem to calculate factorial of any of these .

Comment: You are starting and adding 1 each time through the loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: You are using the variable `a` for the value `n` of the assignment, and using `n` for a different value that needs a variable.  Nothing is fundamentally wrong with that.  But it is a source of confusion and you are better off doing less to try to confuse yourself.

Comment: @ameyCU: The factorial is calculated as you go with `f = f * n` inside the loop.

Comment: Adding a series of numbers in descending sequence of magnitude (as is simplest for this problem and as you are apparently attempting) is less accurate in floating point than adding the same numbers in ascending sequence.  I can't guess whether your instructor expects you to learn programming that well/soon but maybe you should anyway.

Comment: @ameyCU changing the loop as you suggest to compute (2n)! more conveniently would be easier (than my later suggestion) for just the subtask of computing (2n)!.  But then it would be harder to select which values to add together (not VERY hard, but enough harder).  So it is worth a slightly messier way to get (2n)! to avoid any mess in deciding which values to add together.

Comment: I am so sorry for confusing all of you guys. I used 'a' and 'n' interchangeably. I have used 'n' for "count". 'a' is the variable which the user inputs. I have updated the question. Hope its all clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accumulate the sum while checking the counter `n` and only  calculate the even factorials:

```
int n;
double sum = 1;
cin >> n;
for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i{ 
   if(i % 2 == 0) sum += 1 / factorial(i);
}
```

In your code:

```
 while(n <= a)
 { 
    f = f * n;
    // checks if n is even; 
    // n even if the remainder of the division by 2 is zero  
    if(n % 2 == 0){
        s += 1 / (float)f;
    }
    n = n + 1; 
 }
```

Comment: My code is already calculating the factorial. It is also calculating the sum which is equal to 1 + 1/2! + 1/3!.. 1/n!. But according to my question I need  omit odd factorials from the denominator so that it looks something like this - 1 + 1/2! + 1/4! + 1/6!... What changes should I make to my code?

Comment: @Devansh Kumar just edited the answer to include your comment. :)

Comment: That would be a lot of excess work, if it were not for the bug making it just an infinite loop.  It is unnecessarily far from the OP's original version for no good reason and also incorrect, so all around not a good answer.

Comment: I can't seem to get the first part @simplicisveritatis 
Sorry, but I am a complete newbie.

Comment: @Devansh Kumar is it more clear now? Is it something else that you need to be clarified?

Comment: Total change (now more similar to the OP's version) but you are no longer computing factorial at all.  The limitation to even should have applied to only the addition, not the multiplication.

Comment: Figured it out. Moved f=f*n out of the if body. Works Perfect.
Seems like I was right. He also updated the answer to the same.

Comment: @Devansh Kumar nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have almost everything you need in place (assuming you don't want to make design changes based on the issues brought up in the comments).

All you need to change is what you multiply `f` by in each step.  To build up n! you are multiplying by `n` in each step.  To build up (2n)! you would multiply by `2*n*(2*n-1)`

Edit:  Your second theory about what the instructor wants would need only slightly more of a change.  Your inner loop could be replaced by

```
   while(n < a)
   { 
        f = f * n * (n+1);
        s += 1 / f;
        n = n + 2;
   }
```

Edit2:  To run your program I made several changes for I/O things you did that don't work in my copy of GCC.  Hopefully those won't distract from the main point of the following code.  I also added a second, more complicated and more accurate method of computing the answer to see how much was lost in floating point rounding.

So this code computes the answer twice, once by the method I suggested you change your code to and once by a more accurate method (using double instead of float and adding the numbers in the more accurate sequence via a recursive function).  Then it display your answer and the difference between the two answers.

Running that shows the version I suggested gets all the displayed digits correct and is only wrong for the values of `a` I tried by tiny amounts that would need more display precision to notice:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double fac_sum(int n, int a, double f)
{
  if ( n > a )
    return 0;
  f *= n * (n-1);
  return fac_sum(n+2, a, f) + 1 / f;
}

int main()
{

   int a, n = 1;
   float f = 1;
   float s = 0;
   cin >> a;
   while(n < a)
   { 
        f = f * n * (n+1);
        s += 1 / f;
        n = n + 2;
   }

   cout << s;
   cout << " approx error was " << fac_sum( 2, a, 1.0)-s;
   return 0;
}
```

For 8 that displays `0.54308 approx error was -3.23568e-08`
I hope you understand the e-08 notation meaning the error is in the 8'th digit to the right of the `.`

Edit3: I changed `f` to float in this post because I had copied/tested thinking `f` was `float`, so parts of my answer didn't make sense when `f` was `int`

Comment: I tried it but its not working. I think the question is somewhat wrong. Maybe what my teacher wants is s = 1 + 1/2! + 1/4! ... + 1/n!. Denominator should have factorial of even numbers only.

Comment: Do you have an example of the right answer for some n that is large enough for that right answer to let us deduce the instructor's intent?  I'm pretty sure what you described in the original post was unambiguous and would be solved by the small change I described in this answer.

Comment: I asked one of my friend he also said that there's something wrong with the question. My best guess about what my instructor wants is - let's say user inputs 8. That means s = 1/2! + 1/4! + 1/6! + 1/8! = 0.543080. Or if he/she inputs 9, then again s =  1/2! + 1/4! + 1/6! + 1/8! = 0.543080. Meaning, the denominator should not take factorials of an odd number.

Comment: The steps of 2 are easily achieved by your choice of using `2*n` in place of `n` or by advancing `n` by 2 rather than 1.  In my two versions of the answer (above an below "edit") I made opposite versions of that choice:  In each case keeping `n` in the same units as `a`.  But those were arbitrary choices and work just as well either way, as long as all the other details are in sync for that choice.

Comment: Be careful in my second version above that `n` is odd and you want to stop on even when `a` is odd.  So it really was important to change the `<=` to `<` for that version.

Comment: I don't understand the part - f = f*n*(n+1). Why are we multiplying with (n+1)?
Also, it's giving a slightly different answer. Put value of a=8, sum=0.543016 whereas using a calculator gives sum = 0.543080. Is it something to worry about?

Comment: It certainly does not give .543016 when I run it, nor can I find any simple bug that would generate that wrong answer.  As for multiplying by (n+1) I'm not sure how to better explain it.  Factorial needs all the numbers multiplied by `n` is going up by 2 at a time, so when `n` is 1 we multiply by 1 and 2.  When `n` is 3 we multiply by 3 and 4, etc.

Comment: Strange. I tried your version and simplicis's version too. Both are giving me .543016.

Comment: Great explanation. Got it. And yes I am using Turbo C++, that might be the culprit.

Comment: Try changing both f and s to `double` instead of `int` and `float`.  Despite copying and testing your code, I completely missed the detail that `f` was an `int`, which is a rather bad idea.  `float` ought to be good enough for `s` but it is better to rule that out as an issue.

Comment: Yes, double did not change anything. It still gives .543016
EDIT - Changing 'f' from int to double did the trick. It now gives .54308

Answer (score 1):

12! is the largest value that fits in an 32 bit integer. You should use double for all the numbers. For even factorials, starting with f = 1 (0!), f = f * (n-1) * n, where n = 2, 4, 6, 8, ... .